# Access virtualhost from another computer

Tags: php, apache, wamp, virtualhost

First of all I want to say that I have read other topic where the similar problem arises, but applying solutions, none has operated what I want.

I have in my computer 1 IP: 192.168.1.217 configured a virtualhost.

C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *: 80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@sfi.com
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/sfi"
    <Directory "c:/wamp/www/sfi">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    ServerName sfi
    ErrorLog "logs/sfi-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/sfi-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

And I have added the following line:

```
NameVirtualHost *: 80
```

In the file `C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\conf\httpd.conf` I have modified the following lines:

```
Include `conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` (remove `#`)

<Directory /> (Grant permissions)
    AllowOverride none
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny, allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory "c:/wamp/www"> (Grant permissions)
     Order Deny, Allow
     Deny from all
     Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Finally, I added to `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`

```
127.0.0.1 sfi
```

The virtualhost works perfectly on the machine that has installed wamp server.

In the machine I want to access my project, I set to `C:\Windows\System32\ drivers\etc\` hosts the following line:

```
192.168.1.217 sfi
```

But not load my project directory.

Is there something I've done wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: What specifically happens when you try to access the server? What does the error_log say?

Comment: No, my virtualhost works well on the local machine. Only I can not be accessed from another machine despite having set my /etc/hosts file on the machine B.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.  What does your browser or a command-line client say on machine B? What do your logs say on Machine A?

Comment: My browser on the machine B says "This page is not available" ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT.

In the machine A (where I set the virtualhost) the log does not return any error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply have a firewall issue, completely outside your httpd configuration.

Comment: Shrug. Windows Firewall?

Comment: Try accessing your website via its ip address. If you can access it with ip address than you have some other issues

Comment: Yes, Windows. I can not access from the IP (ERROR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT).

Comment: Now Google things on configuring wamp for local network access

Comment: I disabled the firewall on the computer where I have installed my server (machine), and could be accessed from the machine B :)

Comment: Not sure but disabling firewall will cause programs not to access network/internet instead check if Apache/wamp are allowed through firewall

Comment: Yes, you should add a rule to allow this access not disable it entirely